# DUI question with keyless ignition

Tags: california, driving, alcohol, nevada

I am aware you can get a DUI just sitting impaired in a car with keys in ignition. I have a car with a keyless ignition. I was wondering what the standard for DUI is in this type of car. I do not drink so I may never be subject to a DUI. Just more curious then anything else.

Comment: Which country and state/province?

Comment: Nevada and california

Answer (score 10):

Pennsylvania is one state sometimes cited as having [such a law](https://www.legis.state.pa.us/WU01/LI/LI/CT/HTM/75/00.038.002.000..HTM), but the law does not refer to "keys in the ignition", instead,

> An individual may not drive, operate or be in actual physical control
> of the movement of a vehicle after imbibing a sufficient amount of
> alcohol...

Similarly [in Washington](https://apps.leg.wa.gov/rcw/default.aspx?cite=46.61.504),

> A person is guilty of being in actual physical control of a motor
> vehicle while under the influence of intoxicating liquor or any drug
> if the person has actual physical control of a vehicle within this
> state...

[California law](https://leginfo.legislature.ca.gov/faces/codes_displaySection.xhtml?lawCode=VEH&sectionNum=23152) is narrower, since

> It is unlawful for a person who is under the influence of any
> alcoholic beverage to drive a vehicle

and this does not include being in physical control. See [Mercer v. DMV](https://scocal.stanford.edu/opinion/mercer-v-department-motor-vehicles-31352) which affirms that the person must have been driving, but it is not necessary to witness the person driving. Keys in the ignition can be evidence that you were driving, likewise a warm engine or tires, car is in gear, you're in the middle of the road. I doubt that any law is stated in terms of "keys in the ignition", more likely it reduces to actual driving, or being in control of the vehicle.

Comment: Iam guessing one would need to read a lot of caselaw to get a handle on this

Comment: Am I right in understanding that even in Pennsylvania or Washington, if someone is drunk and sleeping in their car, even if they've forgotten the keys in the ignition, as long as the car is stationary and the hand brake engaged (i.e. the person is not in physical control of the car's movement and the car is not moving and cannot move), then that person cannot be subject to a DUI charge?

Comment: No, they *are*  in control of the car. Being stationary doesn't thwart a DUI charge, nor does putting on the brake.

Comment: What if they were to put the keys in the ignition, get out, get drunk, and then get into the passenger side/rear seats of the car. They are no point drunk, and able to reach the controls of the vehicle. Would that be a sufficient seperation for them to not count as in control? If not, what constitutes control?

Comment: @user1937198 There seems to be a number of contradictions in your comment, what do you mean?

Comment: This will likely get more complicated with self-driving cars. Currently, technology is not advanced enough (and might never be)  to have full human self-awareness, so even in self-driving mode the car might give the control over to the driver if the software finds itself in a situation it's not programmed for. However, if the technology improves, there might come a time where it will become an interesting legal question how much in control a driver was, if he was in a self-driving car and the computer was in full control all the time (as the human might have taken over the control).

Comment: @vsz they are already testing cars with no steering wheel and the legal framework has already been started: https://www.cnet.com/roadshow/news/nhtsa-self-driving-cars-law-no-steering-wheels-pedals-autonomous/

Comment: @vsz: If it's an L2-or-lower car (i.e. like what Tesla sells right now), then IMHO the average judge is going to call that a DUI, because the driver is supposed to continuously monitor the car's actions and take over immediately if anything unsafe occurs. An L4-or-higher car is probably *not* going to be a DUI, at least while self-driving is engaged, because it must not require human inputs while in that mode. The tricky case is going to be L3, where the car is "fully" self-driving, but can automatically disengage if the software is unsure what to do.

Comment: @Kevin If I were making the rules, I'd want a more strict DUI standard for any system that requires the human to take over in some systems, since it requires a quick reaction by someone who is not likely to be paying as close attention as an active driver.

Comment: @Barmar: By definition, that does not include L4 and L5 self-driving cars (which don't exist, because the technology isn't there yet).

Comment: @Kevin Right, I was talking about the "tricky" L3 case. I don't think it's that tricky at all in this case -- you need to be even more alert than L1-L2 because you have to switch from non-driving to driving mode when alerted.

Comment: I'm just waiting to see case where they find the guy sleeping in the bar parking lot with the engine running, environmental control set to automatic, and the parking brake set. I'm prepared to show this isn't driving and demonstrates no intention to drive.

Comment: @user6726 Surely some motion must be involved. I don't understand how the law could draw the line anywhere else. E.g. I am drinking at home and I could easily go to my garage and drive my car. How do you draw a line between that and a DUI?

Comment: @Kevin : even an "L4-or-higher" might have the issue that although it would be fully self-driving, a drunken driver might do something stupid, like turning it off (unless the car is designed to detect drunkenness and not allow such interference in that case)

Comment: With my car, having the keys in my pocket allows me to unlock the doors and enter my car, and allows me to press a button to start the engine. Until the engine button is pressed, which is hard to do by accident, the car is safely parked and can’t drive. And I could sit on the passenger seat and reach to that engine button, which would be very dangerous because I’m practically not in control of the car. Wondering how that would count.

Comment: @gnasher729  Many states will arrest you for being drunk and in the car, period.  There are dfefenses, but some states have very high burdens of proof on the offender.  You might not like it, but it is the law of the land in many states.

Comment: @Thomas, it isn't hard to find out that some states will aboslutely arrest you without any motion of the car.

Comment: @TigerGuy But what's the legal standard?

Comment: @Thomas the legal standard tends to be "contorl of the vehicle" which is then adjudicated in court.  Very few people are willing to actually take cases to court in the US because how punishing losing is (like jail time).

Answer (score 1):

### Keyless Ignition Probably Just Lowers the Bar For *Constructive Control* of a Vehicle

The general legal principle would be *actual vs constructive*: physical evidence vs circumstantial evidence. As popular as some shows have made lines like "they only have circumstantial evidence" – still, circumstantial evidence can absolutely be enough.

In OP's jurisdiction of Minnesota (my own too), for example, [*State v. Florine*, 226 N.W.2d 609 (Minn. 1975)](https://www.courtlistener.com/opinion/2212905/state-v-florine/) has long been the standard for an aspect on *constructive possession*, where there is no *physical* evidence of a possession as an element of the violation of law – but there is substantial *circumstantial* evidence of a violation. In OP's fact-pattern, the related principle would be *constructive control* of a vehicle.

OP alludes to those jurisdictions which have allowed *keys in the ignition* to serve as an element proving constructive control of a vehicle. Meanwhile, if simply pushing a button were enough to effectuate the same act as turning a key, then courts in such a jurisdiction would likely be fine with finding constructive control of the vehicle where a person is simply sitting in the car (with the [key fob](https://www.keylessentryremotefob.com/what-is-a-key-fob/)).